# F# Fsharp.Data Type Provider Exception

Tags: f#, type-providers, f#-data

I am getting this when trying to parse a simple csv string. I am running F# out of VS 2013, the dll says it is version 4.3.0.1 which I thought was F# 3.1. My Fsharp.Data dll is 1.1.10.

I am trying to run this as part of an nunit test using resharper. The snippet does work in interactive mode.

Here is the code:

```
open FSharp.Data

type TestCsv = CsvProvider<"test,taht\n1,1">
let x = TestCsv.Parse "test,taht\n1,1"
let tests = x.Data |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.test) 
tests |> Seq.head
```

And the result:

```
System.Exception : Couldn't parse row 1 according to schema: Method not found: 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption`1<System.String> FSharp.Data.RuntimeImplementation.Operations.AsOption(System.String)'.
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: How do you run it? Your snippet works just fine in a clean FSI session.

Comment: Ah, the plot thickens. So it does work for me in Interactive mode, but not when running an nunit test with resharper.

Comment: Not at all, this may explain the source of the problem. Just ensure that `FSharp.Core` and `FSharp.Data` are available for your test execution environment. As a first step, make sure you can execute a simplest F# test that uses FSharp.Core.

Comment: I am a bit new to F#, would this snippet use FSharp.Core?  let x = [1;2;3];; Assert.AreEqual(1, x|>Seq.head) because that worked when running in resharper.

Comment: Yes, `Seq.head` comes from F# core library. Unfortunately, I do not use Resharper test runner so cannot be more specific, but somehow it must have way to list libraries to be delivered into test run environment.

Comment: So, I tried to locate Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpOption from just inside the editor with autocomplete, and I have Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Option, but nothing called FSharpOption.

Answer (score 1):

FSharp.Data 1.1.10 doesn't support F# 3.1/VS2013. Please try with the prerelease version 2.0.0-alpha3 and let us if that works. Make sure both the unit test project and the library project are using the same version of FSharp.Core (either 4.3.0.0 or 4.3.1.0)

Comment: just FYI came out the absence of support is not an obstacle for this particular snippet to run under FSharp.Core 4.3.1.0 and FSharp.Data 1.1.10 within VS2013. Out of curiosity, it also runs under MSTest when being configured correctly.

Comment: I find it weird that it works in FSI 3.1, as when running in-proc of a F# 3.1 compiler, FSharp.Data 1.1.10 would get the wrong version of FSharp.Core linked, that's why you get the errors about not finding FSharpOption

Comment: Nevertheless it also builds and runs just fine being built as a console application with target framework `.NET 4.5` and target runtime `F# 3.1 (FSharp.Core, 4.3.1.0)`. If you're interested, I can provide any extra details off-line.